# Objective-C - Is there any way to group methods together an use this group information in code?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

Take MyClass and it has a lot of methods. Some are there for a particular role, and other methods for another.

Is there any way to group them "per role" **and be able to use that information in code** in figuring out the methods group and using it?

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  But you should completely familiarise yourself with **delegates**, **categories** and **protocols**. Note too that, quite simply, making more and better Classes would serve you well. (i.e., your one huge class should really have many separate classes performing the same concepts.)  Finally you say: "MyClass and it has a lot of methods".  Unfortunately it is then **bad code**, all scripts (in all programming paradigms) should be very short, 100-200 lines is the absolute max.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of are protocols, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

With this method:

```
- (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol
```

you can check if an object implements a particular protocol.

Answer (score 1):

"Take MyClass and it has a lot of methods. Some are there for a particular role, and other methods for another".

The question is the answer, your class is doing way too much. A class for each role sounds like a good start, and perhaps one to delegate from.

Can't say how you should break the class up from here, but that you should is inarguable.

Answer (score 0):

If your class has a lot of methods, split it into smaller classes with fewer methods.